# Book suggestion to prepare the grounds for studying functional Analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, book-recommendation

Hi guys I have 2 month semester break in February and March and I am planning to take a course on functional analysis in 4 months. I have taken a very elementary course on Linear Algebra(Gilbert Strang Mit Ocw) and a very short course (5 week) on a bit advanced linear algebra(first 5 chapters of Peter D Lax.I am thinking of getting more comfortable with the structure of linear operators. I am confused between Linear algebra by Peter D Lax and Halmos(Finite Dimensional vector spaces) . Which one would you recommend?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you taken a course in analysis and/or topology? If not then that's the most pressing prerequisite for functional analysis.

Comment: @neuguy I have read the first 7 chapters of Rudin's principal of mathematical analysis and the first two chapters of Rudin's real and complex analysis and the first two chapters of steins' Real analysis, measure and integration theory. I am also taking a course on stochastic calculus and have self studied some probability theory and intend to read the first 3 chapters of Rick Durett's Probability theory and its essentials over the break. But what about Linear algebra, I havent studies Jordon forms, generalized eigenvalues and spectral theorem...? What do you recommend?

Comment: @neuguyI havent taken any course on topology but I do know the basic notions like open sets, convergence , weak convergence my linear algebra professor talked about a little in the 5 week advanced course on linear algebra, and the very basic definitions and properties of T1, T2 , T3 spaces which i studied myself from wiki and on a need based approach . But I haven't studied a real semester long course or read a book onn topology

Answer (score 0):

I usually expect someone going in Functional Analysis to have a working knowledge of Rudin's Principle of Mathematical Analysis (at least chapters 1-5 and 7). Some Complex Analysis and Measure Theory don't hurt, either.

Comment: I have read the chapters you mention of Rudin's Principals of Mathematical analysis and have a some what working knowledge of Lebesegue integration theory . What would you recommend for linear algebra? I just want to be more mathematically mature before I take on functional analysis in 4 months.